# Is it month of year or the month of year?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct:

- With the marketplace opening in July of 2017.
- With the marketplace opening in the July of 2017.

I've usually seen the latter being written but have recently seen the former in a  few places. Which is correct?

Comment: I think the former is right. But you can say _the July elections_ or _the July edition_ etc when talking about particular incident or anything that happened in that month.

Comment: Funny how it works. I've usually seen the former being written, but have recently seen the latter. In exactly one place: this question.

Comment: I've not seen it written, but have certainly heard plenty of BrE speakers using "the July of...". I'd associate the usage with people talking slowly and being a little unsure of what the date is that they're trying to remember.

e.g. "Remember, Derek, we met them at Sonya's wedding?  That would have been in the July of 2017, just before you had your hernia op."

However, I would agree with John's answer and always recommend not using "the"

Comment: Both are correct, but in different circumstances. (By the way, "marketplace opening" is something I've never noticed, in 60 years of listening. Did you mean "market opening" or what, please?)

Answer (score 1):

I would say **With the marketplace opening in July of 2017.**

Months aren't generally preceded with *the*. You wouldn't use it either in some cases such as *"... in week 10 of 2017"*.

On the other hand, you would use *the* in cases such as *...the Christmas of 2017*.